# How can I get the field value from preprocess_field?

Tags: theming, 9

I would like to get the content of the field with is formatted text to manipulate it a bit (strip from HTML tags and limit) and display it as another variable in twig.

How can I get the value of the field?

This is what I've written so far, and I tried to output the value in the "if statement", but no luck so far:

```
function bootstrap4grow_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['field_name'] == 'field_training_seo') {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all in the `$variables`. Consider using Xdebug to find out yourself.

```php
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_field().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['element']['#field_name'] === 'field_MYFIELD') {
    /** @var \Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemList $items */
    $items = $variables['element']['#items'];
    foreach ($items->getValue() as $delta => $item) {
      // Depending on the field type you find the value in $item['value'],
      // $item['target_id'] etc.
      $value = $item['value'];
      // ....
    }
  }
}
```